# What is wrong with my character comparison conditional?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, short-circuiting

I have a simple subroutine here that takes in a char array and returns a boolean value.

There is something wrong with my conditional. I tested it by passing a single character string "A", and so check_char = 97 and using short-circuit the conditional should give false for check_char != 'a'. The subroutine should return 1. But it always returns 0. Why is this? Something wrong here that I'm just not noticing?

```
/*
 * Checks string of characters and returns 1 if string is a valid DNA sequence and
 * returns 0 if string is not a valid DNA sequence.
 */
int is_valid_dna(char *sequence){
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < ( sizeof(sequence) / sizeof(sequence[0]) ); i++ ){
                int check_char = tolower(sequence[i]);
                if( check_char != 'a' || check_char != 'c'   
                        || check_char != 'g' || check_char != 't' ){
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        /* If the subroutine made it this far, then the sequence is a valid DNA sequence */
        return 1;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone. Passing in the size of the array and using ANDs in the conditional worked out perfectly.

Comment: in c/c++ pointers don't know how many elements they have, so you should add another param that would indicate num elements in array

Comment: @2501          I believe that would be a valid DNA sequence. and this isn't supposed to be a serious program. To be honest it's one of my old projects from a class I took years ago, and I'm reprogramming it for fun / C practice.

Comment: @user3370603 Nevermind, my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using short-circuit the conditional should give false for check_char != 'a'

Yes it does, but since you're using `||` the short-circuit would be to abort the rest of the condition if the answer were true: we only need one of the clauses to be true to make the whole thing true, so we can stop one we've found one true. But it's false, so you continue on to `check_char != 'c'` which is true and so we short-circuit the rest of the condition and return 0.

Did you mean to use `&&` between your conditions, not `||`?

Comment: hmmm, yes I understand. I still get the same result when I use AND.

Comment: Changing the `||` to `&&` works for me. Here's an ideone demo: http://ideone.com/82ySP1

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this what you want:

```
int is_valid_dna(char *sequence, int numChars){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numChars; i++){
        int check_char = tolower(sequence[i]);
        if (check_char != 'a' && check_char != 'c'
            && check_char != 'g' && check_char != 't'){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    /* If the subroutine made it this far, then the sequence is a valid DNA sequence */
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the length. You can probably use strlen here instead to compute numChars, or just keep increasing i until `sequence[i] == 0` (tested before the toLower)

Comment: Still not understanding why that is necessary. Perhaps I am not understanding character pointers in C completely.

Comment: @Rup: yes you can do that as well, but i prefer to pass in explicit #chars- off course my preference would be to deal with std::string

Comment: @user3370603: it is true with every pointer in C/C++- they are not like C#/Java style arrays that understand what and how much they contain. A pointer is address to a raw memory. Thus ideally you should pass in numChars (other way would be to use strlen, but if you get there why not use std::string instead)

Comment: I see. I will update to use strlen. Also I'm coding this in C, not C++.

Comment: That's a distinction between `char[]`, where sizeof will give you the length of the whole array, and `char*` where sizeof will give you the size of a pointer.

Comment: @Rup           aha! Thanks, I updated the subroutine to use a passed in length and not sizeof.

Answer (score -1):

I would code it this way:

```
int is_valid_dna(char *sequence)
{
    for ( ; ; sequence++)
    {
        switch (*sequence)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
            case 't':
            case 'T':
            continue;

            case '\0':
            return 1;

            default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That is a nice example, but it doesn't answer the problem OP presented. Consider addressing the actual question first and then add your example.

Comment: "...and I'm reprogramming it for fun / C practice. " -- he can learn more with this code, ... moreover it is faster than "strlen/if" approaches,... that was an unfair vote down!!